# Reading csv file with right dimension

Tags: r, data.table

In R i want to read the csv file `data.csv`. The 'character set' is 'Unicode (UTF-8)' The file should look like this

```
ss11 009
ts10 114
...
```

So we have dimension 2000 times 2.

In R I write this

```
read.csv(file=".../data.csv", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

but when I type `dim(data)` I get `2000 1` but I should have `2000 2`.
When I type `head(data)` I get

```
ss11009
ts10114
...
```

How can I read the csv file so I get all data with the right dimension ?

Comment: Try using `data.table`'s `fread()` instead of `read.csv()`. You can set the column types with the `colClasses` argument but probably won't need to.

Comment: If it is a csv file, the separator is certainly not a tabulation.

Comment: What should I set the seperator to be?

Comment: As it's name said, as CSV file has Comma-Separated Values. Try after removing `sep="\t"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(data.table)
dt <- fread("data.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
dt
#      V1  V2
# 1: ss11   9
# 2: ts10 114
str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "ss11" "ts10"
#  $ V2: int  9 114
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: I have data.table and I type library(data.table). But when I type fread(file="../data.csv", encoding="UTF-8") R gives me this error message: Error in fread(file = "/data", fileEncoding = "UTF-8",  : 
  unused arguments (file = "/data", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Comment: @OlePetersen  You need version `1.9.6` at least.

Comment: I have the latest version of R.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get data.table version 1.9.6 for R if I use ubuntu?

Comment: @OlePetersen  Did you simply try to remove `sep="\t"` in `read.csv`?

Comment: When I remove sep="\t" I get the error message. If I type sep="," I also get the error message.

Comment: I solve the problem by using sep=";". This works fine for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to open your csv file with text editor like vim and check the field separator rather than double click your csv file which would induce Microsoft Excel to open your file.

Comment: @OlePetersen `install.packages("data.table")`